# Having an issue targeting a HTML element using SCSS/CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I am currently trying to get an icon to float to the right. This can easily done by adding `style="float:right"` or adding an ID, but I am trying to target the icon specifically within the code I have.

My HTML:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>    
        Photography 
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </h4>
  </a>
</div>
```

I want the `<i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>` to float right by targeting classes that begin with `fa-chevron` so i can also target `fa-chevron-down`.

Here is my SCSS:

```
.panel-heading {
    padding: $panel-heading-padding;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    //@include border-top-radius(($panel-border-radius - 1));
    color: #000;

    > .dropdown .dropdown-toggle {
        color: inherit;
    }

.fa {
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: $mogoturquoise;
}

a {
    h4 {
        color: #000;

          //Doesn't work
          i[class^="fa-chevron"] {
            float: right;
          }

          //Works
          .fa-chevron-up{
            float:right;
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Why isn't my attribute selector working is this scss?

Comment: `i[class*="fa-chevron"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[class^="fa-chevron"]` is an [substring matching attribute selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings).

It doesn't target classes. It targets attributes.

Your class attribute looks like this `class="fa fa-chevron-up"`: It does not begin with `fa-chevron` it begins with `fa fa-chevron`.

You should add an additional class to solve this:

```
`class="fa fx-chevron fa-chevron-up"`
```

You can then target it with a regular class selector:

```
.fx-chevron {
```

Alternatively you can use a different substring attribute selector, one that isn't anchored to the start of the string.

```
[class*="fa-chevron"]
```

Comment: Thank-you for your explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother with "beginning with", you can easily use the "contains" `[class*="fa-chevron"]`

Answer (score 1):

I found that:

```
i[class^="fa fa-chevron"] {
  float: right;
}
```

fixed it.

I'm not too sure why the first version doesn't work...